# how to compare a variable to a time format?

Tags: python, if-statement, time, format, telegram-bot

I need the variable entered by the user to look like the time *(for example 15:25)*, if it is not called else
[image: my code]

```
if message.text == ???:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Напомню вам о тренировке в {message.text}')
      schedule.every().day.at(message.text).do(bot.send_message,message.chat.id, 'Время тренировки!')
      while True:
         schedule.run_pending()
         time.sleep(1)
else:
      firts = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Вы неправильно указали формат времени, попробуйте еще раз.')
      bot.register_next_step_handler(firts, gonap)
```

I only came up with the idea to directly write

```
if message.text == "%Y-%m"
```

,but this did not give any result

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *[strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)*

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date_1 = "15:25"
my_date_2 = "25:25"

try:
    datetime.strptime(my_date_1, "%H:%M")
    print(True)
except ValueError:
    print(False)
    
try:
    datetime.strptime(my_date_2, "%H:%M")
    print(True)
except ValueError:
    print(False)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

So your code will be something like this:

```
try:
    datetime.strptime(message.text, "%H:%M")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Напомню вам о тренировке в {message.text}')
    schedule.every().day.at(message.text).do(bot.send_message,message.chat.id, 'Время тренировки!')
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
except ValueError:
    firts = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Вы неправильно указали формат времени, попробуйте еще раз.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(firts, gonap)
```

Comment: As an improvement, it seems like `at` has to parse the string as a valid time anyway, so you might as well let *it* raise an exception if `message.text` is invalid. `s = schedule.every().day.at(message.txt)`, then use `s.do(...)` when appropriate if no exception was caught.

Comment: The `while` loop should almost certainly *not* be in `try` block; maybe in an `else` clause instead.